# Collapsible Property ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a form with different areas. In each area I have the option of **collapsible: true** .
That what it does is load all the areas. What I need is that when I open the form appear the closed areas and then go open as you need them.

```
config.items = [{
        xtype       : 'fieldset',
        title       : this.i18n.fieldSetEvalMotriz,
        collapsible : true,
        autoHeight  : true,
        defaults    : {
                        anchor: '100%'
                    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this

```
collapsed:true
```

in that fieldset to show that fieldset collapsed by default and then open as you need.